# Localstack/Airflow problem: Lambda in localstack unable to connect to Airflow REST API

Tags: docker, docker-compose, airflow, localstack

**Short history:** I have a lambda within localstack that is being triggered by an S3 event.  That is working just fine.  Then, the lambda is supposed to send a request to AF's REST API to trigger a DAG. The works also when just running the Python code as standalone (not in the lambda).  The AF instance is a separate docker container outside of the localstack container.

**Problem:** I'm getting a "connection refused" error

**Tried:** Set up a connection (aws_default) in Airflow (in the "Extra" field): {"host": "http://localhost:4566"}

**Question:** Is this possible and if so, how do I configure either localstack and/or Airflow to allow it?